# Please tell me how to bind event when activitybar icon is clicked

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is there any way to connect activitybar event?

I searched on the VSCode API site but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you don't attach event handlers to anything. You don't have access to the DOM actually. Instead you register a command in package.json and register a command handler for it. For details read the [extension documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).